# Drop down wont select horizontal selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I have created a dropdown in my excel spreadsheet and selected values across my horizontal axis. The issue is on the drop down menu only the first value shows.

Can I get round this by perhaps entering the values into a macro when the page loads?

Below is my selections:

```
Date
Incident
Problem
End to End Outage
Service Outage
Client
Service
Area
Business Area
Fact
Cause
Action
Due Date
Owner
Root Cause Code
Strategic Client Impact
Completed Date
PM Owner
Region
IFC
# of Strat Clients Impacted
Downtime Minutes
Internal Impact Only
Comments
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the values from the horizontal cells in a string and then use it for your data validation.

**Assumption:**

Let's say you data looks like as shown below and you want to show the list from `A1:M13` in cell `D4`

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim sList As String

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> This is the range which has the horz list
        Set rng = .Range("A1:M1")

        '~~> Get the values of each cell and store it in a string
        For Each aCell In rng
            sList = sList & "," & aCell.Value
        Next

        sList = Mid(sList, 2)

        '~~> Adding the data validation to say Cell D4
        With .Range("D4").Validation
            .Delete

            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=sList

            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output:**

When you run the above code, you will see the result

[image]

Comment: I added the code as suggestd but it does not show in the drop down?

Comment: Did you make the necessary changes? Like changed the Sheet name to the relevant sheet name, or changed the ranges to your ranges?

Comment: I did.... i changed range to   Set rng = .Range("A2:Y2") & sheet to   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FCA")

Comment: And what about `.Range("D4").Validation` ?

Comment: I have not chnaged that

Comment: And why not? Do you want the validation in that cell?

Comment: Wht i have done is on the first row , i have marged all the cells and entered a imput box, drop down and submit button all into one cell

Comment: Are you by any chance using ActiveX ComboBox as dropdown? Can you upload your file to a file sharing site and share the link here?

Comment: I am... i am on works PC and the file sharing sie are blocked sadly

Comment: Then I guess it will have to wait. I can't keep on guessing what you have and what you don't :) Post the sheet when u can and we will take it from there...